# Why doesn't this script run like it should?

Tags: python, subprocess

I tried to write a script which reads the cells in a `.xlsx` file (result is the name of an `.eml`) and check if the `.eml` is in the directory `/vagrant/E-Mails`.
It executes a shell script which puts all `.eml` files in the directory into the `eml.txt` file.

If I do:

```
>> python optest.py
```

it still says:

> E-Mail not found

...but there are those `.eml` files in the directory.

Can you help me to solve this please?

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import subprocess

testcases = load_workbook('/vagrant/Excel/testcases.xlsx')
testcases_ws = testcases.active
profil = testcases_ws['A2']
print profil.value


testmails = load_workbook('/vagrant/Excel/testmails.xlsx')
testmails_ws = testmails.active
eml = testmails_ws['A2']
eml = eml.value
print eml
path = "/vagrant/E-Mails/"

subprocess.Popen(['sh', "/vagrant/test.sh"])

if eml in open("eml.txt", "r"):
        print "E-Mail ´found"
else:
        print "E-Mail not found."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if eml in open("eml.txt", "r"):
```

Here, you're using the `in` operator on the file object returned by `open`. This will only succeed if `eml` exactly matches a complete line in the file, including a terminating newline. For a more lenient matching approach, try using `in` on the string contents of the file instead.

```
if eml in open("eml.txt", "r").read():
```